# Defining custom setf for class in lisp

Tags: oop, common-lisp

Suppose I have a class called board:

```
(defclass board ()
 ((blocker    :accessor blocker    :initarg :blocker    :initform  0))
```

According to this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201175894) I can define a custom setf for blocker by:

```
(defmethod (setf blocker) (new-blocker (b board))
  (setf (slot-value b 'blocker) new-blocker))
```

However, steel bank common lisp will say function not defined, even though I have evaluated it. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Note: you don't need to define (setf blocker) given that the :accessor keyword already defined one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct.  Note that you are redefining the already existing setf method that you created by specifying `:accessor blocker`.  SBCL will give you a `style-warning` about that.

Your mistake is somewhere else.  Are you in a different package, perhaps?  Try to show the steps you have taken in your IDE to compile and load those forms, and to attempt to run that method invocation.

Comment: I tried to check if setf-blocker is defined by using (fboundp 'setf-blocker), but it returned nil. And when I tried defining it myself it still complains that the function isn't defined.

Comment: Works in my env, with latest SBCL and OS X. Your defclass form is missing a closing parenth; is this the problem? Good book though; also check out 'The Art of the MetaObject Protocol'

Comment: @Mark: That function is not called `setf-blocker` but `(setf blocker)`.  Show the code you are trying to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a generic function before defining any methods.

```
(defgeneric (setf blocker) (new-blocker board))
```

See [this](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html) chapter in Practical Common Lisp for an example.

Comment: Incorrect. If no generic function exists, one will be created for you. See http://l1sp.org/7.6.2 for details.

Comment: Oh you're right, SBCL only emits a STYLE-WARNING. Btw your link doesn't work. ([7.6.2](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_fb.htm))